# why Array occupies more memory compared to collection?

Tags: java

Why does an array take more memory than a collection? Is it because with arrays the memory is allocated when the array is initialized?

Arrays are recommended when we want better performance. Is this because the array stores elements in contiguous memory chunks?

Comment: Why do you think an array occupies more memory than a collection? I doubt that is true, especially when the array / collection is full. Do you have a source for that info?

Comment: I was learning about difference between Array and Collection. One of the difference is  2)Array is recommended when you want more performance but it takes more memory space than a collection.

Comment: Also, arrays do not always give better performance. It depends what you are doing with the data. For example, if you are often deleting elements in the middle of the collection, a LinkedList will give better performance since it requires two pointers to be updated instead of a ton of elements being shifted to the left.

Comment: [This site](https://vanillajava.blogspot.ca/2011/07/java-how-much-memory-do-different.html) contradicts your claim. Note that there is a large difference, however, between using primitive data type and wrapper class.

Comment: Simply wrong. ArrayLists are **implemented** using arrays. The **only** reason to prefer arrays over Lists is when you have to deal with **primitive** data such as byte, char, ... on **large** scale. As a `List<Boolean>` requires a certain overhead (memorywise) compared to a simple boolean[]. But beyond that, your assumptions are flawed.

Comment: @nhouser9 I would be careful about that. Cache locality is often horrible for linked lists and in many cases will reverse your claim. (I am thinking in terms of C++ as well when it comes to vectors and lists.)

Comment: Thanks.I understand that Insertion and search in array would be faster. Can you explain whether the memory will be allocated for the array when it is initialized? if it is allocated, it means array is occupying more space than collection right. because in collection we will not specify the size and we can add elements as we want and it will increase in size automatically.

Comment: @synchronizer deleting an element from an array when all other elements need to be shifted is O(n). doing the same for a `LinkedList` is O(1). While cache locality may make this faster with an array for small data sets, it's not possible for that to hold true for large data sets per the definition of O(f(n)).

Comment: @synchronizer of course, if your data set is always small, i agree there may be cases where some strange optimization using cache locality is possible, though i'm not really familiar with the topic

Answer (score 3):

Your question has two parts. I will address them both below.

**Memory**

Arrays do not always take more memory than `Collection`s. Arrays pretty much store a bunch of objects in order. Most `Collection`s store additional information. For example, `LinkedList` stores pointers to the previous and next elements in the list. That means that `LinkedList` takes more space than array. However, array often does take more **contiguous** space then `Collection` because the JVM will try to allocate the whole array in contiguous memory, which it does not need to do for all `Collection`s.

**Performance**

As for performance, everything depends on what you are doing with the data. For example, if you are accessing a bunch of random indeces in your data, array will be very fast. But if you are deleting a bunch of random indeces in your data, array will be **much** slower than `LinkedList`. This is because when an element is deleted from an array, all the elements to the right need to be shifted over. When an element is deleted from a `LinkedList`, all we need to do is update two pointers. In other words, sometimes array will give better performance than `Collection`, sometimes it will give worse performance. It all depends on what you are doing with your data and what type of `Collection` you are using.

Comment: @user6426361 no problem. if this helped you i would appreciate it if you upvoted and / or accepted the answer

Comment: You could be around long enough to understand that a newbie with +1 rep cant upvote.